# Can mods cast non-binding close votes?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This question, [The meaning of "did not immediately respond to requests for comment" [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186272/the-meaning-of-did-not-immediately-respond-to-requests-for-comment), was closed by the following users, *in this order*:

> **Janus Bahs Jacquet, tchrist♦, Rory Alsop, user66974, FumbleFingers**

What's tchrist♦ doing in the middle? I thought that when mods decided to close a question, their vote was binding?

From the [help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators):

> Moderator votes are binding. Any place we have voting — close, open, delete, undelete, offensive, migration, etc — that vote will reach the threshold and take effect immediately if a single moderator casts a vote.

How has this happened?

Comment: In July 2014 tchrist had not yet been [elected as a moderator](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: @Mari-LouA oops, didn't check the date 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Moderators can't cast non-binding votes.

Before moderators were moderators, their votes were ordinary votes and listed in exactly the same way as other votes (that is, in the order received).

When a moderator is elected, **every** mention of their name gains a diamond. Having existing comments and votes suddenly gaining a diamond is something which candidates [should] consider when running for election.

In that list of users, you can see that "user66974" isn't actually a user. This is the same mechanism: the account which was active in July 2014 isn't now, and **every** mention of it now bears its generic ID.

I *believe* that by the same token, if a moderator gives up that role, the diamond is removed from every mention of their name: this could result in questions appearing to have been closed by fewer than five votes with no mention of why that happened (which the diamond would explain).

Comment: At least we don't behead an ex-moderator.

Comment: I didn't even think to look at the date! It was on the homepage.

Comment: @ab2 the reverse is true though, once beheaded, the diamond will be taken away.